# Tableau / SQL Filling In Missing Data

Tags: sql, tableau-api

So, I have a bit of a strange thing - it's come up before, but my tool of choice in the past has been either R or Python and I can usually take care of this with a bit of code magic, but being new to Tableau, I'm not sure how to handle this....

I have a SQL statement as a data source that joins three tables. Let's call the first one the "Customer" table and the 2nd one the "Questions" table. The Customer table contains basic information, including the customer ID number. The "Questions" table is formatted in a way that makes it a little difficult to deal with. It contains the customer number, of course which is used as the key to join the two. It also contains two other columns - ATTRIBUTE_NM (the questions name) and ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_TXT (the answer to said question). My problem is there are several questions- 9 to be exact. It looks like this:

```
CustID    ATTRIBUTE_NM    ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_TXT
000001    Question 1      NULL
000001    Question 2      Blah Blah
....      .....           .....
000001    Question 9      Declined to Answer
```

Ok, so there are some potential combinations here. Either a customer can have all questions answered, in which case, they all appear for that customer. Some cases a customer can answer some questions, but not all, in which case, some questions are "NULL" and others are answers. And finally, we have customer that were in the database before the questions were a thing, so they do not appear in that Questions table at all.

I know all of the questions that are possible. My goal is to use Tableau to create a dashboard that looks like this:

```
CustomerID    Question_1    Question_2    Question_3    ....
00001         Answered      Not Answered  Answered
```

This is an internal request for a team that is working to identify customers, which questions they answered and which ones they didn't (if the customer doesn't exist in the question table, we assume they didn't answer them).

So a few things here - I need to figure out how to turn the ATTRIBUTE_NM from data in a column/field into columns themselves. This isn't that hardd - I can create a dimension with each question name and some logic to look at ATTRIBUTE_NM to see if that answer exists or is NULL. My issue is when the questions for that customer do not exist at all. How do I check for a "DOESN NOT EXIST" or something of the like?

In the past I have done this with dates, for example in R, but what I had to do is create a reference table that had all the date combinations and merge it with the read data to fill in the gaps. I think that is a possibility here, but I've never done that with Tableau or SQL. I'm wondering if, during the join, I can somehow fill those gaps in, since I'm doing a LEFT JOIN between the Customer Table and the Questions... Thank you all so much, in advance, for any help you can give me!

Comment: Not a full answer, but if you create a set of the questions and cross join that against your original set, you can see which don't exist.

Comment: @Andy - Yeah, i think that is what I have resolved myself to, but now I'm still trying to figure out the SQL to do that. Another option is rather than creating new columns would be to just fill in the missing data, but I'm still scratching my head there as well.

Comment: Left join would give you customers that are not in the Questions table at all. But it looks like maybe you could do a Union since there are only 9 questions and define the 9 questions somehow. Like Select CustomerID, Question_1 as.....Question_2 as ..... etc.

Comment: @wavery - But to select them like that, would't Question 1, etc have to be columns. Right now the questions are content of a single column....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
SELECT
  CUSTOMERID,
  CASE WHEN QUESTION_1 IN (NULL, 'DECLINED TO ANSWER') THEN 'NOT ANSWERED' ELSE 'ANSWERED' END AS QUESTION_1,
  CASE WHEN QUESTION_2 IN (NULL, 'DECLINED TO ANSWER') THEN 'NOT ANSWERED' ELSE 'ANSWERED' END AS QUESTION_2,
  CASE WHEN QUESTION_3 IN (NULL, 'DECLINED TO ANSWER') THEN 'NOT ANSWERED' ELSE 'ANSWERED' END AS QUESTION_3,
  CASE WHEN QUESTION_4 IN (NULL, 'DECLINED TO ANSWER') THEN 'NOT ANSWERED' ELSE 'ANSWERED' END AS QUESTION_4,
  CASE WHEN QUESTION_5 IN (NULL, 'DECLINED TO ANSWER') THEN 'NOT ANSWERED' ELSE 'ANSWERED' END AS QUESTION_5,
  CASE WHEN QUESTION_6 IN (NULL, 'DECLINED TO ANSWER') THEN 'NOT ANSWERED' ELSE 'ANSWERED' END AS QUESTION_6,
  CASE WHEN QUESTION_7 IN (NULL, 'DECLINED TO ANSWER') THEN 'NOT ANSWERED' ELSE 'ANSWERED' END AS QUESTION_7,
  CASE WHEN QUESTION_8 IN (NULL, 'DECLINED TO ANSWER') THEN 'NOT ANSWERED' ELSE 'ANSWERED' END AS QUESTION_8,
  CASE WHEN QUESTION_9 IN (NULL, 'DECLINED TO ANSWER') THEN 'NOT ANSWERED' ELSE 'ANSWERED' END AS QUESTION_9
  FROM(
  SELECT
  CUSTID as CUSTOMERID,
  (CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NM = 'Question 1' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_TXT ELSE '' END) AS QUESTION_1,
  (CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NM = 'Question 2' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_TXT ELSE '' END) AS QUESTION_2,
  (CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NM = 'Question 3' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_TXT ELSE '' END) AS QUESTION_3,
  (CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NM = 'Question 4' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_TXT ELSE '' END) AS QUESTION_4,
  (CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NM = 'Question 5' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_TXT ELSE '' END) AS QUESTION_5,
  (CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NM = 'Question 6' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_TXT ELSE '' END) AS QUESTION_6,
  (CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NM = 'Question 7' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_TXT ELSE '' END) AS QUESTION_7,
  (CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NM = 'Question 8' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_TXT ELSE '' END) AS QUESTION_8,
  (CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NM = 'Question 9' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_TXT ELSE '' END) AS QUESTION_9,
  FROM Questions
  )
```

I tried the Union and I think there is a way to do it that way but you are right, it wasn't working.

Comment: You got it. I played around for a bit, and that is what I landed on. I'm not gonna bother posting what I had since it's the same - you get the credit for this one. The only piece I was missing was the "Answered", "Not Answered" part, but you have that. Cheers!

Comment: I send you a chat invite, I didn't want to flood the post with specifics, so I thought maybe we could has those out there and  one of us could post the final solution to this issue. Just wanted to give you a head's up.

Comment: No problem, I have not done chat on this site so I will check it out. Glad it worked!

Comment: Let me know if you have issues finding the room. I listed you as someone with "write access", so if you go to Chat and look at the "Invited" tab you should see it there.